# Notice: Undefined index: name in E:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 60

Tags: php, html

I am getting this error 
Notice: Undefined index: name in E:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 60
Here the code that I have, please help me out to get rid of this error. I am new to coding

```
<?php
$root = '';
$path = 'images/';

$bhatti = array(
'1'=>'Katrina wants to meet you',
'2'=>'Kareena wants to meet you',
'3'=>'Aishwarya wants to meet you',
'4'=>'Shahrukh wants to meet you',
'5'=>'Aamir wants to meet you',
'6'=>'Shahid kapoor wants to meet you',
'7'=>'Parineeti wants to meet you',
'9'=>'Priyanka wants to meet you',
'10'=>'She wants to meet you',
'11'=>'Kristen wants to meet you',
'12'=>'Shriya wants to meet you',
'13'=>'Sonakshi wants to meet you',
'14'=>'Deepika wants to meet you',
'15'=>'Cameron wants to meet you',
'16'=>'Ajay wants to meet you',
'17'=>'wants to meet you',
'c'=>' wants to meet you'
);
$img = $bhatti[array_rand($bhatti,1)];
?> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="diabetes, about diabetes,alcohol and diabetes,heart attack,Rheums" />
    <meta name="description" content="Click here to know the reason">
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $img; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $img; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/"; echo $path . rawurlencode($img); ?>.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />

</head>
<body>

<?php if($_GET['name']){ ?>
<div><img src="<?php echo $path . $img ?>.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<?php }else{?>
<div><img src="oops.png" alt="" /></div>
<?php } ?>

<p>Developed by <a href="https://www.Facebook.com/Ali42726"> Ali Hasan </a>.</p>

<p>Thank you for visiting </p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am writing this to show a random image every time a user enters, and display image title as the page name.

Comment: First in this line <div><img src="<?php echo $path . $img ?>.jpg" alt="" /></div> you have a error. correct <img src="<?php echo $path . $img; ?>.jpg" alt="" /></div> You miss ";"

Comment: Second, in this line <?php if($_GET['name']){ ?>  where do you get 'name'?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error at

```
<?php if($_GET['name']){ ?>
```

You need to check if name is set in global variable $_GET or not.

Try using

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['name'])){ ?>
```